# Windows Service could not start - Error 1053

Tags: c#, windows-services

I had searched a lot in the Web, but I didn't find a solution that would work for me.

I had developed a Windows Service with C#. When I install it on my desktop, then it works without a error. I can stop, start or restart it and it do all what it should do. My current desktop is using Windows 10 1909.

When I install this release on the Windows Server 2016 Version 1607 then I got the folling error when the service should start:

[image: Picture Error 1053]

I do not know what I have to change in my OnStart-Function.

```
public partial class Webshopfiletransfer : ServiceBase
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    private static string logfile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Webshopfiletransferslog-" + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".txt";

    public Webshopfiletransfer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        writetolog("Service started");
        try
        {
            SetTimer();
            aTimer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            writetolog("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            aTimer.Stop();
            aTimer.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            writetolog("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void SetTimer()
    {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        transferfiles("download");
        transferfiles("upload");

        if (!File.Exists(logfile))
        {
            string createText = "Logfile created" + Environment.NewLine;
            File.WriteAllText(logfile, createText);
        }
    }

    private static void transferfiles(string modus)
    {
        //This function works when the service is started
    }

    private static void writetolog(string messagetext)
    {
        string appendText = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": " + messagetext + Environment.NewLine;
        try
        {
            File.AppendAllText(logfile, appendText);
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you for a good tip.

Comment: A server you have limited access to the file system.  Are you running the service as Admin?  Can you change the read/writing of the files to a Network folder where you have more access?

Comment: Do you get any error written in the logs?

Comment: Can this happen when the service is on fileserver installed? Access is on the folder for Every